# PHP/Nginx layer adding to response time when loading simple MySQL query from RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, nginx

I've been dealing with this for a long time now and I've narrowed down where the problem lies.

Initially, I thought the problem was either my medium EC2 instance or my medium RDS instance but after connecting to my RDS via MySQL command line from my EC2 and experiencing no delay in query load/response time, I see now that the only things left to be causing this issue are PHP or Nginx.

Here is the code I'm executing:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("database-3...us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "admin", "...", "prod_db", 3306);
$start_time = microtime(true);
mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `product_categories` ORDER BY `list_order` ASC");
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "execution time: ".(($end_time-$start_time)*1000)."ms<br><br>";
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing most of the time when this code is executed:

[image]

However, a good chunk of time, I'm seeing this:

[image]

You can see it takes 10x as long some of the time to execute these queries.

This wouldn't be such a big deal if this was the worst of it. But my website is suffering immensely because of this delay. My page loads are sometimes taking 2-3 seconds because of 10ms query responses taking 100ms each.

Here is my nginx config file for my site:

```
server {
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;

set $no_cache 1;

if ($arg_trycache = 1) {
    set $no_cache 0;
}   

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php;

server_name server.com www.server.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ ^\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;     
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    
    fastcgi_cache ZONE_1;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = 1024M";
    #fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    
    #limit_req zone=two;
    #limit_req zone=one burst=40 nodelay;
}

location ~ \.php$ { # will be used for any PHP request except 'index.php'
    return 404;
}

location ~ /api/v1/app-content/search-all.php {
    #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_cache ZONE_1;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    
    fastcgi_cache ZONE_1;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1m;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = 1024M";
    #fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    
}


    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }


listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/chain.crt; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/server.key; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I'm truly at a loss at this point. I thought for days that it was somehow the RDS instance I have running but after eliminating that possibility by connecting via command line, I'm back at square one.

So essentially my question is this: is it possible that PHP itself or Nginx are the culprit here? Keep in mind that my PHP code is as simple as possible. No extra layers on top, just straight mysqli_ functions.

Comment: That's possible. You can remove Nginx from the mix and do another test. If your PHP script can run stand-alone, from EC2, you can run `php yourscript.php` repeatedly every few seconds/minutes and observe the output. If your output shows 3s delay sporadically as well, you have a connection issue between EC2 and RDS. Next test could be to backup the database, restore it on MySQL on EC2 (different server than the PHP one) and see if your PHP script is consistently faster with MySQL on EC2. That'll tell you if EC to RDS connection is the culprit (assuming they are in the same region/AZ).

Comment: I ran a PHP script via command line on my EC2 (thus bypassing Nginx I believe) and the delay is still there. It's actually quite bad too. What does this mean? Is there some PHP setting related to this? And yes my EC2 and RDS are in the same zone.

Comment: You mean "most of the time" the response time of the same query execution are around 0.4x ms but "some of the time" it will be around 3.x ms ?

Comment: Correct. And it scales up. I have another set of queries that ordinarily run at 6ms but about 20% of the time they run at 60ms each so it really slows things down.

Comment: That means Nginx has nothing to do with the delay. The issue is between your EC2 instance and RDS. What's your RDS instance type?

Comment: I don't think the issue is the EC2 or the RDS instance because I connected directly to my RDS from my EC2 via command line mysql and there was no delay at all. It's only when PHP gets involved that there's a delay.

Comment: @zedfoxus Ok so, if I run queries from the command line from my EC2 directly to my RDS, I get 0.00 sec response time about 95% of the time, and the other 5% of the time I'm getting 0.01 sec, which would be 10ms. So I'm not sure if I can count that as a delay? I guess technically it is a delay but it's way less than the 60-100ms I'm seeing on my web site so I'm not sure what to make of this. Is the problem the EC2-RDS connection or is it PHP?

Comment: Is your server having a huge traffic need (many requests made per second) ?

Comment: @KenLee no, not at all. It's not even live yet. It's just me testing alone.

Comment: @tfrizzzzz this is a very interesting problem. Do you have an index on list_order column of product_categories?

Comment: @zedfoxus yes I do have an index on it. And there are only 15 or so rows in that table anyways. To be clear, I've tested again and again and the problem persists. My PHP script that executes this simple query, which I'm running via terminal on my EC2, is showing very fast execution times on my query about 95% of the time, but that other 5%, it's taking 10x as long. This is permeating my entire site and resulting in very long page loads that 5% of the time.

Comment: @tfrizzzzz If you are open to doing a Zoom session, get a hold of me from Twitter or email me from my site. If that's not a possibility, let me know how you run your test. Do you run the PHP script from command line in series like `php script.php` -> hit Enter -> after results show up run again? If that is so, open a MySQL terminal session `mysql -u ... -h ... -p` and watch `show processlist` and watch the # of open connections.

Comment: Well, I had a friend run the same exhaustive test on his ec2 (he also has mediums) and he was seeing the same behavior. Most of the time the queries executed instantly, but a small fraction of the time, his query took 10x or even 100x as long to finish. So maybe none of this was a problem at all and this is just how RDS operate? Thanks for the offer but I think after seeing this, I'm just going to let it go...

Comment: It wasn't as big a deal as him because he was loading queries using JavaScript after the page load finished so it always looked like his pages were loading faster. But maybe they actually weren't loading any faster and this masked the problem.

Comment: That's a common trick - display the page, and then load the dynamic contents by JS/Jquery -- this is especially useful if the data to be loaded is rather large in size